# SSRS 2008 ReportViewer page 0 of 0

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am rendering a series of reports in a winform webbrowser passing parameters directly to the SSRS reports directly in the URL string.

http://server/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fFolder%2fThisReport&rs:Command=Render&Param1=30083&Param2=1

I get data, but the report often (the problem is inconsistent) only renders the first page, lists 0 of 0 pages and the find, search and move to page controls are all disabled

When I run the same report without trying to use the report viewer & not passing parameters it renders all pages normally and nothing is disabled.

http://server/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fFolder%2fThisReport

I've tested the parameters and the only difference in what works and what doesn't is using the reportviewer to render the report in the browser.  (The same behavior does still occur very rarely when not using the reportviewer.  With the reportviewer it is a common occurrence.)  I haven't found anything I can do to modify the behavior of the reportviewer from the URL or a way to not use the reportviewer and still pass the parameters I need to pass for the users.

I don't have admin access to the SSRS settings, so I'm hoping to solve this by making a modification to what/how I am passing commands and parameters in the URL.  If SSRS settings are the only known way to deal with this issue, that would still be good to know.

Answer (score 1):

It is to do with caching.  In report manager go to the processing options of the report and change to cache a temporary copy of the report